# Django| generate random url based on URl or PATH from urlconfig

Tags: django

I have a question regarding generating example urls according the Django url and path.

For example if I have 2 urls like:

```
 path('example/<int:example_id>/', views.some_view, name='example')

 url(r'^example/(?P<example_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.some_view, name='example')
```

Is it possible to generate somehow by Django built-in means example full-urls for tests like:

```
example/234/
example/93/
example/228/
etc…
```

randomly.

For different urls based on concrete name + `regex` or `converter` parameters?

In other words where in source code Django understands that `<int:example_id>` is an integer and so on. If I have something like : 1) I expect `example/`  2) I expect `int` -  I would be able to use it to generate random example url.

Hopefully this is  clear...

These urls are just an example. Real urls will differ.

Thank you.

Comment: This simply boils down to substituting it to a regex: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/converters.py#L6 and then when the parameters are captures automatically call `to_python` on the string capture: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/converters.py#L8-L9

Comment: As for generating random URLs, it is not said that there exists an object behind this `example_id`, so the URLs you generate eventually can lead to a 404 by the view.

Comment: But for a regex, you can generate random strings, especially since this eventually boils down to a *finite state machine*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words where in source code Django understands that `<int:example_id>` is an integer and so on.

This is in essence looking for `<…:…>` patterns in the `path`. Django has furthermore a set of *path converters*. The standard ones are `int`, `str`, `slug`, `uuid`, `path`, but you can define your *own* path converters.  Indeed, the Django documentation has a section [*registering custom path converters*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) that explains how you can design your own path converters.

What a path basically does is constructing a regex. It thus searches for patterns like `<int:example_id>`. Since you here used `int`, the [**`IntConverter`** [GitHUb]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/urls/converters.py#L5-L12) is used:

> ```
> class IntConverter:
>     regex = '[0-9]+'
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         return int(value)
>
>     def to_url(self, value):
>         return str(value)
> ```

Here it will thus replace the `<int:example_id>` by `(?<example_id>[0-9]+)`, where the `regex` part thus will be used.

A `path(…)` does not only constructs a regex. It also automatically maps the captured items to a Python object by calling `.to_python(…)`. This thus means that if you work with `re_path(r'^example/(?P<example_id>[0-9]+)/$', …)`, then `example_id` will be a string, but for `path('example/<int:example_id>/', …)`, it will automatically call `int(…)` on the captured string, and thus pass an `int` object. Often that does not make much difference.

This also holds when you *serialize* an object: you can pass a value, and it will call `.to_url(…)` on the object to convert it to a string representation for the generated URL. This thus means that you can write custom path converters that thus perform more sophisticated conversions.

> I expect `example/` 2) I expect `int` - I would be able to use it to generate random example url.

Well eventually it boils down to a regular expression. A regular expression can be converted into a *finite state machine*, so we can generate random valid strings. For example [**`exrex`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex) is capable to generate all valid strings (this is often an generator that will keep proposing new strings), or random strings that match the regular expression. It is however not said that because it matches the `path(…)`, that it will be sensical for the view. If you for example use this `int` as the primary key of a `Post` object it is fetching, then for random URLs, it is likely that you will generate URLs for non-existing `Post`s.

Comment: very fruitfull explanation. Thanks a lot